# jQGrid not showing last page and total records returned from server

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, paging

I'm using jQGrid with asp handler to display records in grid. Everything working fine with client side paging, searching and sorting. Below is my code.

```
jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({
            url: 'http://localhost:58404/JQGridHandler.ashx',
            datatype: "json",
            colNames: ['Id', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Last 4 SSN', 'Department', 'Age', 'Salary', "Address", 'Marital Status'],
            colModel: [
                        { name: '_id', index: '_id', width: 50, stype: 'text' },
                        { name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', width: 100, stype: 'text', sortable: true, editable: true },
                        { name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', width: 100, editable: true },
                        { name: 'LastSSN', index: 'LastSSN', width: 100, editable: true },
                        { name: 'Department', index: 'Department', width: 100, align: "right", editable: true },
                        { name: 'Age', index: 'Age', width: 40, align: "right", editable: true },
                        { name: 'Salary', index: 'Salary', width: 100, align: "right", editable: true },
                        { name: 'Address', index: 'Address', width: 100, sortable: false, editable: true },
                        { name: 'MaritalStatus', index: 'MaritalStatus', width: 100, sortable: false, editable: true }
                      ],
            rowNum: 10,
            mtype: 'GET',
            loadonce: true,
            rowList: [10],
            pager: '#jQGridDemoPager',
            sortname: '_id',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: 'asc',  //desc
            caption: "List Student Details",
            editurl: 'http://localhost:58404/JQGridHandler.ashx'
            //// ****** here i placed the onPaging: //.......
        });

        $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('navGrid', '#jQGridDemoPager',
                   {
                       edit: true,
                       add: true,
                       del: true,
                       search: true,
                       searchtext: "Search",
                       addtext: "Add",
                       edittext: "Edit",
                       deltext: "Delete"
                   },
                   {   //EDIT
                       //                       height: 300,
                       //                       width: 400,
                       //                       top: 50,
                       //                       left: 100,
                       //                       dataheight: 280,
                       closeOnEscape: true,     //Closes the popup on pressing escape key
                       reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                       drag: true,
                       afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                           if (response.responseText == "") {

                               $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid'); //Reloads the grid after edit
                               return [true, '']
                           }
                           else {
                               $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid'); //Reloads the grid after edit
                               return [false, response.responseText]//Captures and displays the response text on th Edit window
                           }
                       },
                       editData: {
                           EmpId: function () {
                               var sel_id = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                               var value = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, '_id');
                               return value;
                           }
                       }
                   },
                   {
                       closeAfterAdd: true,     //Closes the add window after add
                       afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                           if (response.responseText == "") {

                               $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid')//Reloads the grid after Add
                               return [true, '']
                           }
                           else {
                               $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid')//Reloads the grid after Add
                               return [false, response.responseText]
                           }
                       }
                   },
                   {   //DELETE
                       closeOnEscape: true,
                       closeAfterDelete: true,
                       reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                       closeOnEscape: true,
                       drag: true,
                       afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                           if (response.responseText == "") {

                               $("#jQGridDemo").trigger("reloadGrid", [{ current: true}]);
                               return [false, response.responseText]
                           }
                           else {
                               $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid')
                               return [true, response.responseText]
                           }
                       },
                       delData: {
                           EmpId: function () {
                               var sel_id = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                               var value = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, '_id');
                               return value;
                           }
                       }
                   },
                   {//SEARCH
                       closeOnEscape: true

                   }
            );
```

Now I need server side paging and tried with the code [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030302/jqgrid-client-side-sorting-with-server-side-paging-data-disappears/9047197#9047197) by Oleg. I placed that cod in jqgrid under editurl.

```
onPaging: function (which_button) {
                var pageNumber = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "page");
                $(this).setGridParam({ datatype: 'json', page: pageNumber }).triggerHandler("reloadGrid");
            },    
            loadComplete: function (data) {
                var $this = $(this);
                if ($this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'datatype') === 'json') {
                    $this.jqGrid('setGridParam', {
                        datatype: 'local',
                        data: data.rows,
                        page: data.page,
                        records: data.totalRecords,
                        total: data.total
                    });
                    this.refreshIndex();

                    if ($this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'sortname') !== '') {
                        $this.triggerHandler('reloadGrid');
                    }
                } else {
                    $this.jqGrid('setGridParam', {
                        page: $this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'pageServer'),
                        records: $this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'recordsServer'),
                        lastpage: $this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'lastpageServer')
                    });
                    this.updatepager(false, true);
                }
            }
```

In loadComplete data contains the no. of records per page, and and displayed. but grid not showing the total recods returned from server. It's showing `view 11 - 20 of 10`.
I'm also getting total records from server in `data.totalRcords`.

Is it correct place where i placed the `onPaging`?
Oleg, I'm new to jqgrid put me in right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: onPaging: function (which_button) is handling with server side? if yes then would you like to show your server side code...?

Comment: Using Jquery, you can paginate a grid on two ways.. that is server side and client side... if you are getting totalRecords, then client side pagination is suitable

Answer (score 0):

In my case, on server side.. i was using following code to paginate , here is a sample code and its using int pageNumber =  // variable for page number
            int pageSize //variable for page size
            string sortOrder = string.Empty; // variable for the sort direction
            string sortIndex.. 
hope that it will help you

```
public ErrorLogPagedList GetFixedListOfExceptionLogDetails()
    {
        var objErrorLogPagedList = new ErrorLogPagedList(); //object to return
        var objExceptionLogBa = new ExceptionLogBa(); //Ba layer object
        var objGlobal = new Global();

        try
        {
            //get the values from the service call
            int pageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request["page"]); // variable for page number
            int pageSize = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request["rows"]); //variable for page size
            string sortOrder = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Request["sord"]) ?? string.Empty;
                // variable for the sort direction
            string sortIndex = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Request["sidx"]) ?? string.Empty;
                // variable for the sort column name

            //if the page value is less than 0, then start with 1
            if (pageNumber <= 0)
            {
                pageNumber = 1;
            }

            //if the page size is less than equal to 0 take default value
            if (pageSize <= 0)
            {
                pageSize = 15;
            }

            if (objGlobal.IsNotNull())
            {
                if (objGlobal.CurrentRole.IsNotNull())
                {
                    objErrorLogPagedList.Rows = objExceptionLogBa.GetFixedListOfExceptionLogDetails(pageNumber,
                                                                                                    pageSize,
                                                                                                    sortOrder,
                                                                                                    sortIndex);
                    long totalNumberOfrecords = objExceptionLogBa.GetTotalNumberOfExceptionRecords();
                        //variable to get total number of pages

                    //set the rest of the values for the CategorypagedList object
                    objErrorLogPagedList.Records = totalNumberOfrecords;
                    objErrorLogPagedList.Page = pageNumber;

                    /*if totalnumberofrecords is 7 and page size is 10 then it will return 0 so in that case it will take default value of 1 page*/
                    if (totalNumberOfrecords/pageSize <= 0)
                    {
                        totalNumberOfrecords = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //else if the number of records is 10 then it will return 1
                        if (totalNumberOfrecords%pageSize == 0)
                        {
                            totalNumberOfrecords = totalNumberOfrecords/pageSize;
                        }

                            //else if the number of records is 11 then it will return 1, but there should be 2 pages so +1
                        else
                        {
                            totalNumberOfrecords = (totalNumberOfrecords/pageSize) + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    //set the value for total pages
                    objErrorLogPagedList.Total = totalNumberOfrecords;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                        }

        return objErrorLogPagedList;
    }
```