# jqGrid set records count

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid that points at an external API, which I have no control over.  This external API has two endpoints:

- **Data** Endpoint - Returns the table row data
- **Count** Endpoint - Returns pagination counts etc.,

Based on user input the jqGrid filter gets converted into the appropriate query-string to filter the external API's **Data** and **Count** Endpoints.

I have jqGrids `url` being dynamically built based off of user input and targets the **Data** Endpoint...and during the `loadBeforeSend()` event it calls the **Count** Endpoint to get the latest pagination information based on users filter.

I am using the jsonreader capabilities:

```
jsonReader: {
                    root: 'products',
                    id: 'id',
                    records: function () {

                        return gridTotal;
                    },
                    total: function () {
                        // var totalPages = (gridTotal + reqOptions.limit-1) / reqOptions.limit;
                        var totalPages = Math.ceil(gridTotal / reqOptions.limit);
                        console.log('totalPages: ' + totalPages);
                        return totalPages;
                    },
                    page: function () {
                        //var totalPages = Math.ceil(gridTotal/20);
                        console.log('currentPage: ' + reqOptions.page);
                        return reqOptions.page;
                    }
                },
```

Sample of the loadBeforeSend method:

```
loadBeforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
    settings.url = _newUrl || endpointURL;

    // Lets fetch our data count...this may change as items get published so lets fetch during load
    products.count(accessToken, _filterQuery)
        .success(function (resp) {
            // This is the total number of products that match our current search
            gridTotal = resp.count;
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
}
```

Fetching from the **Data** Endpoint works really well, the issue is how to call the **Count** Endpoint and update the pagination data.

Tried the following:

- Using `setGridParam` for records, last_page, etc.,
- Using `getGridParam('reccount')`
- Just update the html to look correct (not effective since paging will be off)

Is there a way to

- Manually fire off the XHR for jqgrid URL...so I can request the Count first and when it returns then go fetch the Data?
- Rerun the jsonreader functionality once the Count returns and `gridTotal` is set
- Use a promise like structure to resolve records count

---

Updated to show @Oleg solution

```
    loadBeforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
        settings.url = _newUrl || endpointURL;

        // Lets fetch our data count...this may change as items get published so lets fetch during load
        products.count(accessToken, _filterQuery)
            .success(function (resp) {
                // This is the total number of products that match our current search
                gridTotal = resp.count;
gridTotal = resp.count;
                            grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', {
                                page: gridOpts.jsonReader.page(),
                                records: gridTotal,
                                lastpage: gridOpts.jsonReader.total()
                            });
                            grid[0].updatepager(false, true);
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.error(err);
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that I correctly understand your problem. In the case you can first make loading of the main data from the **Data** Endpoint. Then (inside of `loadComplete`) you can start *new* `$.ajax` request manually to get the data from the **Count** Endpoint and to update the pagination data inside of `success` callback of the `$.ajax`.

What you need to do for the updating the pager is:

1. setting of `page`, `records` and `lastpage` parameters of jqGrid based on the data returned from the **Count** Endpoint.
2. call of `$("#grid")[0].updatepager(false, true);` which will uses the above options and to refresh the information on the pager.

You can see in [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9047197/315935) and example of usage of `.updatepager(false, true)`.

Comment: Yes your understanding of the question is accurate, I was hoping I explained it well enough, nice job =) ... Excellent I ran across that 'old answer' before but 'pageServer', 'recordsServer', and 'lastpageServer' were null.  Instead of grabbing from 'getGridParam' using those fields I just recall my jsonreader functions.  Thanks a lot!!  @Oleg #FTW #Again